# Can't run my apps in Visual Studio 2012 after developer's license update

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8

VS 2012 sometimes asks me to update my developer's license. But after update I can't run any apps that I started before.
If I try to build my old apps Visual Studio raises error message like that:

> Unable to activate Windows Store App 'ed6553be-8f11-43a3-a62e-e49949772b16_9xvn524qbsn3j!App' The activation request failed with error 'This app can't run because of trouble with license. Try again.' See help for advice on troubleshooting the issue.

So, the help button redirects me here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28vs.debug.error.app_activation_failure%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true

But there are nothing useful. This happens all time after license updating with every app, that has been started before updating. How to fix this? I need to build again my old apps.

Comment: Just rebuild them so they'll use the updated test license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting `bin` and `obj` folders of your project as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388586/this-app-failed-to-launch-because-of-an-issue-with-its-license).